# How to resize a batch of images for use with Pytorch Linear Regression?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to create a simple linear regression neural net for use with batches of images. The input dimensions are `[BatchSize, 3, Width, Height]`  with the second dimension representing the RGB channels of the input image.

Here is my (broken) attempt at that regression model:

```
class LinearNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, Chn, W,H, nHidden):
        """
        Input: A [BatchSize x Channels x Width x Height] set of images
        Output: A fitted regression model with weights dimension : [Width x Height]
        """
        super(LinearNet, self).__init__()
        self.Chn = Chn
        self.W = W
        self.H = H
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(Chn*W*H,nHidden)   # hidden layer
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(nHidden, Chn*W*H)   # output layer

    def forward(self, x):
        torch.reshape(x, (-1,self.Chn*self.W*self.H)) # FAILS here
        # x = x.resize(-1,self.Chn*self.W*self.H)  
        x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
        x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
        x = x.resize(-1,self.Chn, self.W,self.H)
        return x
```

When sending in a batch of images with dimensions `[128 x 3 x 96 x 128]`  this fails on the indicated line:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (36864x128 and 36864x256)
```

How should the matrix dimensions be properly manipulated to use these pytorch functions?

**Update** Based on a (since deleted) comment I have updated the code to use `torch.reshape`.

Comment: The error is saying that your x has a size of `128x3x96x128` and it has `4718592` elements, however, you are trying to turn this into `36864` elements only. You are missing the `*128`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1** As a possible solution, you can get a batch size from input `x` with `x.shape[0]` and use it in reshape later

```
import torch

batch = torch.zeros([128, 3, 96, 128], dtype=torch.float32)

# -1 will compute last dimension automatically
batch_upd = torch.reshape(batch, (batch.shape[0], -1))

print(batch_upd.shape)
```

Output for this code is

```
torch.Size([128, 36864])
```

**Solution 2**
As another possible solution you can use [flatten](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html)

```
batch_upd = batch.flatten(start_dim=1)
```

will result in the same output

As to your next problem, consider going through the modified `forward` code:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = x.flatten(1)  # shape: [B, C, W, H] -> [B, C*W*H]
    x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))      # activation function for hidden layer
    x = self.predict(x)             # linear output
    x = x.reshape((-1, self.Chn, self.W, self.H)) # shape: [B, C*W*H] -> [B, C, W, H]
    return x
```

Here is the successful usage example:

```
ln = LinearNet(3, 96, 128, 256)
batch = torch.zeros((128, 3, 96, 128))
res = ln(batch)
print(res.shape)  # torch.Size([128, 3, 96, 128])
```

Comment: Will not the `flatten` cause loss of context?  The linear should not squash all of the rows together into one big vector: it needs to simultaneously solve all 128 (batch size) rows. The `reshape()` seems correct : but it is different from `flatten` no?

Comment: @StephenBoesch It looks like `flatten` is implemented using `reshape` under the hood, you can check it [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ef6356133ebdc4b9b49dd1aac2ca7b3e3f05ca7c/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L814-L839). However, if you are not sure, feel free to use plain reshape ofc.

Comment: Ah i had missed that the `flatten` has parameter `(1)` that leaves the batch size intact